# Text-based adventure game where you fight two enemies per round

Tags: java, game, adventure-game, battle-simulation

This is a text based adventure game, where you need to fight against 2 enemy in every round. The damage dealt and potion heal is a random number.
How can I improve?

Game class:

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] enemyTypes = {"Skeleton", "Giant", "Goblin", "Demon", "Defeated Knight", "Warrior", "Demon Lord"};
        String[] enemyStatsText = createEnemyStats(enemyTypes);
        
        Player player = new Player(150, 3);
        
        System.out.println("How many rounds do you want to play?");
        int maxRound = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int roundCount = 0;
        for (roundCount = 1; roundCount < maxRound; roundCount++) {
            roundStart(chooseEnemys(enemyStatsText), player, roundCount);
        }
    }

    private static String[] chooseEnemys(String[] enemyStatsText) {
        String[] enemies = new String[2];
        enemies[0] = enemyStatsText[randomNumber(0, enemyStatsText.length - 1)];
        enemies[1] = enemyStatsText[randomNumber(0, enemyStatsText.length - 1)];
        return enemies;
    }

    private static String[] createEnemyStats(String[] enemyType) {
        String[] enemyStatsText = new String[enemyType.length];
        int minHealth = 25;
        int maxHealth = 70;
        int minDamage = 15;
        int maxDamage = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < enemyStatsText.length; i++) {
            enemyStatsText[i] = enemyType[i] + ";" + randomNumber(minHealth, maxHealth) + ";" + randomNumber(minDamage, maxDamage);
        }
        return enemyStatsText;
    }

    public static int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
        int range = (max - min) + 1;
        int stats = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
        return stats;
    }

    private static void roundStart(String[] enemies, Player player, int roundCount) {
        System.out.println(enemies[0] + " " + enemies[1]);

        String[] enemyOne = enemies[0].split(";");
        String enemyOneName = enemyOne[0];
        int enemyOneHP = Integer.parseInt(enemyOne[1]);
        int enemyOneDamage = Integer.parseInt(enemyOne[2]);
        boolean enemyOneDead = false;

        String[] enemyTwo = enemies[1].split(";");
        String enemyTwoName = enemyTwo[0];
        int enemyTwoHP = Integer.parseInt(enemyTwo[1]);
        int enemyTwoDamage = Integer.parseInt(enemyTwo[2]);
        boolean enemyTwoDead = false;

        int stopLoop = 1;
        while (stopLoop == 1) {
            System.out.println(" \n \n \n Round " + roundCount + " is starting!");
            System.out.println("Player HP: " + player.getPlayerHP());
            System.out.println(" \n 1: I want to fight \n 2: I want to drink a potion. I have " + player.getPotionCount() + " potions." + "\n 3: Escape");
            int input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            if (input == 1) {
                System.out.println("So, you choose to fight!");
                stopLoop = 2;
                chooseEnemyToFight(player, enemyOneName, enemyOneHP, enemyOneDamage, enemyOneDead, enemyTwoName, enemyTwoHP, enemyTwoDamage, enemyTwoDead, roundCount);
            } else if (input == 2) {
                potionDrink(player);
                System.out.println("You have drinked a potion. Potions remaining: " + player.getPotionCount() + ". Your hp is: " + player.getPlayerHP());

                stopLoop = 2;
            } else if (input == 3) {
                System.out.println("You are escaped. Your score is: " + roundCount);
                stopLoop = 2;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invaild number!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void chooseEnemyToFight(Player player, String enemyOneName, int enemyOneHP, int enemyOneDamage, boolean enemyOneDead, String enemyTwoName, int enemyTwoHP, int enemyTwoDamage, boolean enemyTwoDead, int roundCount) {
        while (enemyOneDead == false || enemyTwoDead == false) {
            int input = 0;
            if (enemyOneDead == false && enemyTwoDead == false) {
                System.out.println("The two enemy is: " + enemyOneName + " with " + enemyOneHP + " health and " + enemyOneDamage + " attack DMG and a " + enemyTwoName + " with " + enemyTwoHP + " health and " + enemyTwoDamage + " attack DMG");
                System.out.println("Which one do you want to hit? The other one can attack you!");
                System.out.println("If you want to fight with the " + enemyOneName + ", type number 1. If you want to fight with the " + enemyTwoName + ", type number 2.");
                input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            } else if (enemyOneDead == false && enemyTwoDead == true) {
                System.out.println("You will fight with the " + enemyOneName + " who has " + enemyOneHP + " HP and " + enemyOneDamage + " attack damage.");
                input = 1;
            } else if (enemyOneDead == true && enemyTwoDead == false) {
                System.out.println("You will fight with the " + enemyTwoName + " who has " + enemyTwoHP + " HP and " + enemyTwoDamage + " attack damage.");
                input = 2;
            }

            if (input == 1) {
                if (enemyTwoDead == false) {
                    System.out.println("So you want to fight with the " + enemyOneName + " first \n");
                }
                enemyOneHP = attackEnemy(enemyOneName, enemyOneHP, enemyOneDamage, player);
                if (enemyOneHP <= 0) {
                    System.out.println(enemyOneName + " is died. \n");
                    enemyOneDead = true;
                }

                playerDamageRecived(player, enemyTwoDamage, enemyTwoName, roundCount);
            } else if (input == 2) {
                if (enemyOneDead == false) {
                    System.out.println("So you want to fight with the " + enemyTwoName + " first \n");
                }
                enemyTwoHP = attackEnemy(enemyTwoName, enemyTwoHP, enemyTwoDamage, player);
                if (enemyTwoHP <= 0) {
                    System.out.println(enemyTwoName + " is died. \n");
                    enemyTwoDead = true;
                }

                playerDamageRecived(player, enemyOneDamage, enemyOneName, roundCount);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void playerDamageRecived(Player player, int enemyOneDamage, String enemyOneName, int roundCount) {
        player.setPlayerHP(enemyAttack(player, enemyOneDamage));
        if (player.getPlayerHP() > 0) {
            System.out.println(enemyOneName + " attacked you! Your hp is: " + player.getPlayerHP());
        } else if (player.getPlayerHP() <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You are dead! Your score is: " + roundCount);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static int attackEnemy(String enemyName, int enemyHP, int enemyDamage, Player player) {
        System.out.println("Which attack do you want to use, your knife (1) or your gun (2)? If you use your knife, you can use a heal potion too, or attack twice! \n");
        int input1 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        if (input1 == 1) {
            enemyHP = enemyHP - player.getPlayerKnifeDamage();
            System.out.println("The enemy hp is: " + enemyHP + ". Do you want to attack again with the knife(1), or do you want to use a potion(2). You have " + player.potionCount + " potions.");
            int input2 = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            if (input2 == 1) {
                enemyHP = enemyHP - player.getPlayerKnifeDamage();
                System.out.println("The enemy hp is: " + enemyHP);
            } else if (input2 == 2) {
                potionDrink(player);
                System.out.println("You have drinked a potion. Potions remaining: " + player.getPotionCount() + ". Your hp is: " + player.getPlayerHP() + "\n");
            }
        } else if (input1 == 2) {
            enemyHP = enemyHP - player.getPlayerGunDamage();
        }
        return enemyHP;
    }

    private static void potionDrink(Player player) {
        player.setPotionCount(player.getPotionCount() - 1);
        player.setPlayerHP(player.getPlayerHP() + player.getPotionHeal());
        if (player.getPlayerHP() > 100) {
            player.setPlayerHP(100);
        }
    }

    private static int enemyAttack(Player player, int enemyDamage) {
        return player.getPlayerHP() - enemyDamage;
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

import static textbasedadventuregame.Game.randomNumber;

public class Player {

    int playerHP;
    int playerKnifeDamage;
    int playerGunDamage;
    int potionCount;
    int potionHeal;

    public Player(int playerHP, int potionCount) {
        this.playerHP = playerHP;
        this.potionCount = potionCount;
    }

    public int getPlayerHP() {
        return playerHP;
    }

    public void setPlayerHP(int playerHP) {
        this.playerHP = playerHP;
    }

    public int getPlayerKnifeDamage() {
        return playerKnifeDamage = randomNumber(15, 25);
    }

    public void setPlayerKnifeDamage(int playerKnifeDamage) {
        this.playerKnifeDamage = playerKnifeDamage;
    }

    public int getPlayerGunDamage() {
        return playerGunDamage = randomNumber(20, 60);
    }

    public void setPlayerGunDamage(int playerGunDamage) {
        this.playerGunDamage = playerGunDamage;
    }

    public int getPotionCount() {
        return potionCount;
    }

    public void setPotionCount(int potionCount) {
        this.potionCount = potionCount;
    }

    public int getPotionHeal() {
        return potionHeal = randomNumber(50, 80);
    }

    public void setPotionHeal(int potionHeal) {
        this.potionHeal = potionHeal;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java is idiomatically very object-oriented, and the current code doesn't quite get there - it has too many statics, and doesn't properly encapsulate the classes that it should. Particularly, `Enemy` should get a class. `Game` can also be instantiated from `main()`.

`roundStart` isn't particularly well-named, since it doesn't just start the round - it runs the entire round.

`chooseEnemys` should be spelled `chooseEnemies`.

Don't pack your enemy stats into semicolon-separated strings - you aren't serializing them to disk or sending them over the network. Just put those stats as members on objects.

You should generalise your code so that it's easy to change the number of enemies per round, not hard-coding everything to two enemies.

Don't write your own `randomNumber` - `ThreadLocalRandom` has what you want.

Don't make a new `Scanner` every time that you need to get input - just make a single instance. If you want to make this testable you can accept it as a parameter to the class constructor, though I haven't shown this.

Avoid writing `\n` as it isn't portable. Use `%n` in format strings instead.

The score is a strange calculation. You get the same score if you run away from every single fight as when you win every single fight. This probably needs refinement.

`You have drinked` should just be `You drank`, and `You are escaped` should just be `You escaped`. `The two enemy is` should be `The two enemies are`. `Is died` should just be `died`. `Recived` is spelled `Received`.

Consider use of `switch` rather than your repeated `if`s when checking input. Also, your input validation is a good start but is not comprehensive - for instance, if the user enters a letter instead of a number your loop will not catch it. The easy way around this is to work with strings and don't bother calling `nextInt`.

Avoid calling `System.exit()`. Instead, let the round logic pick up on the fact that the player is dead.

Remove the word `Player` from all of your methods on the player class, since it's redundant.

Your damage should not be represented as variables on the player class. Delete those and keep your damage calculation functions.

Remove basically all of your `set` methods and constrain your state manipulation to supported operations like taking damage and drinking potions.

Health and damage are continuous quantities. Why not represent them as doubles instead of ints?

### Suggested

**Game.java**

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Game implements Iterator<Round> {
    public final int nRounds;
    private int roundIndex = 0;
    private final Player player = new Player();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many rounds do you want to play?");
        int nRounds = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        new Game(nRounds).run();
    }

    public Game(int nRounds) { this.nRounds = nRounds; }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { return roundIndex < nRounds && player.isAlive(); }

    @Override
    public Round next() {
        roundIndex++;
        out.printf("%n%n%nRound %d is starting!%n", roundIndex);
        return new Round(player);
    }

    public void run() { forEachRemaining(Round::run); }
}
```

**Round.java**

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Round {
    private final List<Enemy> enemies = List.of(
        new Enemy(), new Enemy()
    );
    private final Player player;
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Round(Player player) { this.player = player; }

    public String enemyDescriptions() {
        // Return a string with all enemy descriptions separated by spaces.
        return enemiesAlive()
            .map(Enemy::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }

    public void run() {
        out.printf(
            "%s%n"
            + "Player HP: %.0f%n",
            enemyDescriptions(), player.getHealth());

        while (true) {
            out.printf(
                  "1: I want to fight!%n"
                + "2: I want to drink a potion. I have %d potions.%n"
                + "3: Escape.%n",
                player.getPotionCount());

            String input = scanner.next();
            switch (input) {
                case "1" -> fight();
                case "2" -> drinkPotion();
                case "3" -> out.println("You have escaped.");
                default -> {
                    out.println("Invalid choice!");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public Stream<Enemy> enemiesAlive() {
        return enemies.stream().filter(Enemy::isAlive);
    }

    private void fight() {
        out.println("So, you choose to fight!");

        while (player.isAlive() && enemiesAlive().findAny().isPresent()) {
            Enemy toFight = chooseEnemy();
            attackEnemy(toFight);

            enemiesAlive()
                .filter(enemy -> enemy != toFight)
                .forEach(this::receiveDamage);
        }
    }

    public Enemy chooseEnemy() {
        List<Enemy> alive = enemiesAlive().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Enemy enemy;
        if (alive.size() == 1)
            enemy = alive.get(0);
        else {
            out.println("The enemies are:");
            out.println(
                IntStream.range(0, alive.size())
                .mapToObj(index -> String.format(
                        "%d. %s", index + 1, alive.get(index)
                ))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))
            );

            out.println("Which one do you want to hit? The others can attack you!");
            enemy = alive.get(scanner.nextInt() - 1);
        }
        out.printf("So you want to fight with the %s.%n", enemy.name);
        return enemy;
    }

    private void receiveDamage(Enemy enemy) {
        player.takeDamage(enemy.damage);
        out.printf("%s attacked you! Your health is: %.0f%n",
            enemy.name, player.getHealth());
        if (!player.isAlive())
            out.println("You are dead!");
    }

    private void attackEnemy(Enemy enemy) {
        out.println("Which attack do you want to use, your knife (1) or your gun (2)? If you use your knife, you can use a heal potion too, or attack twice!");
        boolean bonusAction;
        double damage;

        while (true) {
            switch (scanner.next()) {
                case "1" -> {
                    bonusAction = true;
                    damage = player.getKnifeDamage();
                }
                case "2" -> {
                    bonusAction = false;
                    damage = player.getGunDamage();
                }
                default -> {
                    out.println("Invalid choice!");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        damageEnemy(enemy, damage);

        if (bonusAction) {
            out.println("Do you want to attack again with the knife(1), or do you want to use a potion(2)?");
            switch (scanner.next()) {
                case "1" -> damageEnemy(enemy, player.getKnifeDamage());
                case "2" -> drinkPotion();
            }
        }
    }

    public void damageEnemy(Enemy enemy, double damage) {
        enemy.takeDamage(damage);
        out.printf("The enemy health is: %.0f%n", enemy.getHealth());
        if (!enemy.isAlive())
            out.printf("%s died.%n", enemy.name);
    }

    private void drinkPotion() {
        player.drinkPotion();
        out.printf(
            "You drank a potion. Potions remaining: %d. Your health is: %.0f.%n",
            player.getPotionCount(), player.getHealth());
    }
}
```

**Body.java**

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

public class Body {
    public final double startingHealth;
    protected double health;

    protected Body(double health) {
        startingHealth = health;
        this.health = health;
    }

    public double getHealth() { return health; }
    public boolean isAlive() { return health > 0; }

    public void takeDamage(double damage) {
        health = Math.max(0, health - damage);
    }

    public void heal(double amount) {
        health = Math.min(startingHealth, health + amount);
    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Player extends Body {
    private static final ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    private int potionCount;

    public Player(double health, int potionCount) {
        super(health);
        this.potionCount = potionCount;
    }

    public Player() { this(150, 3); }

    public int getPotionCount() { return potionCount; }

    public void drinkPotion() {
        if (potionCount > 0) {
            potionCount--;
            heal(rand.nextDouble(50, 80));
        }
    }

    public double getKnifeDamage() {
        return rand.nextDouble(15, 25);
    }

    public double getGunDamage() {
        return rand.nextDouble(20, 60);
    }
}
```

**Enemy.java**

```
package textbasedadventuregame;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Enemy extends Body {
    private static final ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public static final String[] names = {
        "Skeleton", "Giant", "Goblin", "Demon", "Defeated Knight", "Warrior", "Demon Lord",
    };

    public final double damage;
    public final String name;

    public Enemy(String name, double health, double damage) {
        super(health);
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public Enemy() {
        // Random enemy
        this(
            names[rand.nextInt(names.length)],
            rand.nextDouble(25, 70),
            rand.nextDouble(15, 25)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "%s with %.0f health and %.0f attack damage",
            name, health, damage
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch! I learned a lot from your comment! Thank you for the time and  effort you put into this answer.